# Export custom collectd PostgreSQL metrics to GCP Stackdriver Monitoring

Tags: stackdriver, collectd, google-cloud-stackdriver

## Background

I'm trying to export PostgreSQL replication delay by adding a custom `<Query>`
statement to my PostgreSQL config (original config from [Stackdriver PostgreSQL
Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/postgreSQL)) in
stackdriver-agents collectd configuration
directory.

`/opt/stackdriver/collectd/etc/postgresql.conf`:

```
# This is the monitoring configuration for PostgreSQL.
# Make sure the statistics collector is enabled in your PostgreSQL configuration.
# NOTE: This configuration needs to be hand-edited in order to work.
# Look for DATABASE_NAME, STATS_USER, STATS_PASS, POSTGRESQL_HOST and POSTGRESQL_PORT to adjust your configuration file.
LoadPlugin postgresql
<Plugin "postgresql">

    <Query replication_lag_seconds>
        Statement "SELECT (CASE WHEN pg_last_xlog_receive_location() = pg_last_xlog_replay_location() THEN 0 ELSE EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp()) END) AS log_delay"
        <Result>
            Type "gauge"
            ValuesFrom "log_delay"
        </Result>
    </Query>

    # Each database needs a separate Database section.
    # Replace DATABASE_NAME in the Database section with the name of the database.
    <Database "THE_DATABASE">
        # Host and port are only used for TCP/IP connections.
        # Leaving them out indicates you wish to connect via domain sockets.
        # When using non-standard PostgreSQL configurations, replace the below with
        Host "localhost"
        Port "5432"
        User "THE_USER"
        Password "hunter2"
        Query backends
        Query transactions
        Query queries
        Query table_states
        Query disk_io
        Query disk_usage
        Query replication_lag_seconds  # My custom query
    </Database>
</Plugin>
```

The stackdriver-agent logs confirm that the plugin is loaded and that the plugin
is able to connect to the PostgreSQL server.

```
collectd[30418]: plugin_load: plugin "postgresql" successfully loaded.
collectd[13849]: Successfully connected to database THE_DATABASE (user THE_USER) at server localhost:5432 (server version: 9.4.12, protocol version: 3, pid: 13862)
```

By this time, I would expect to see my "log_delay" metric to show up in
Stackdriver monitoring when looking at metrics for the "Instance (GCE)"
resource. I can see that other PostgreSQL metrics have made it through, more
specifically:

[image: PostgeSQL Metrics]

I also can't seem to find any of the other default `Query [...]` metrics
inherited from the [default PostgreSQL collectd configuration](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Stackdriver/stackdriver-agent-service-configs/master/etc/collectd.d/postgresql.conf)
referenced by [Stackdriver PostgreSQL Plugin Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/postgreSQL):

```
# [...]
LoadPlugin postgresql
<Plugin "postgresql">
    # [...]
    <Database "DATABASE_NAME">
        # [...]
        User "STATS_USER"
        Password "STATS_PASS"
        Query backends
        Query transactions
        Query queries
        Query table_states
        Query disk_io
        Query disk_usage
    </Database>
</Plugin>
```

## Question

1. How do I get my collecd custom replication_lag_seconds metric to show up in Stackdriver Monitoring?
2. Do I need to configure [Custom
   Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/) in order to get
   the metrics to show up in Stackdriver Monitoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stackdriver monitoring agent sends a [set of curated metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#agent) for each [supported third-party application](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/). That set cannot be extended by users -- anything that isn't a curated metric will be ignored by the API and must be sent via the [custom metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/) mechanism.