# Adding custom jmx metrics to google cloud monitoring collectd configuration

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, collectd, google-cloud-monitoring

I've added the JVM Monitoring plugin as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/jvm)

That's all working great and I can, but now I'd like to add more JMX metrics. e.g. MemoryPool specific counters
So I've added this config to `/opt/stackdriver/collectd/etc/collectd.d/jvm-sun-hotspot.conf`

```
<MBean "jvm_localhost_MemoryPool">
    ObjectName "java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=*"
    InstanceFrom "name"
    <Value>
        Type "gauge"
        InstancePrefix "memorypool-usage_used"
        Table false
        Attribute "Usage.used"
    </Value>
</MBean>
```

and

```
Collect "jvm_localhost_MemoryPool"
```

in the `Connection` section

It seems to be valid collectd config but when it's getting sent to Stackdriver/Google Cloud Monitoring it is rejected.

```
012    {#012      "index": 261,#012      "valueErrors": [#012        {#012          "error": {#012            "code": 3,#012            "message": "Unsupported
 collectd id: plugin: \"jvm\" type: \"gauge\" type_instance: \"memorypool-usagecommitted\""#012          }#012        }#012      ]#012    },#012    {#012
"index": 262,#012      "valueErrors": [#012        {#012          "error": {#012            "code": 3,#012            "message": "Unsupported collectd id: plug
in: \"jvm\" type: \"gauge\" type_instance: \"memorypool-usageinit\""#012          }#012        }#012      ]#012    },#012    {#012      "index": 263,#012
"valueErrors": [#012        {#012          "error": {#012            "code": 3,#012            "message": "Unsupported collectd id: plugin: \"jvm\" type: \"gau
ge\" type_instance: \"memorypool-usagemax\""#012          }#012        }#012      ]#012    },#012    {#012      "index": 264,#012      "valueErrors": [#012
    {#012          "error": {#012            "code": 3,#012            "message": "Unsupported
```

Now from what I understand it needs to be added as a custom metric, but [this document](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#auto-creation) suggests it would be auto created.
And indeed when I look at the list of [builtin jvm metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-jvm) I can't see how they map onto the existing ones in the collectd configuration.

e.g. how is `os-open_fd_count` mapped to `os/open_files` ?

It would be helpful to see the actual api request being sent by Google's [custom collectd implementation](https://github.com/Stackdriver/collectd/blob/stackdriver-agent-5.8.1/src/collectd.conf.pod#plugin-write_gcm) but I can't see a way of increasing logging.

I can see from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150437/export-custom-collectd-postgresql-metrics-to-gcp-stackdriver-monitoring) that it's probably custom metrics where I want to be looking but how do I do that in the collectd configuration?

I've tried

```
InstancePrefix "custom.googleapis.com/memorypool-usage"
```

but still no joy.

Has anyone done this before or can offer any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The troubleshooting documents [1] could be helpful to determine what points need to be transformed, as well as to ensure your transformations behave as expected.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/custom-metrics-agent#troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks @shafiq-i, the logging wasn't actually that useful but the rest of the linked page was. I'm not sure how I missed that page when I was trying to get it work before. The key is to rewrite the message to include the `stackdriver_metric_type` metadata. It's very verbose but I have at least got it working. I'll add an answer with my configuration for my original post.

Comment: Can you provide the jvm-sun-hotspot file you used? Am facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

To get this logging I needed to add `stackdriver_metric_type` metadata.

The complete chain is now

```
<Chain "GenericJMX_jvm">
    <Rule "rewrite_custom_jmx">
        <Match regex>
            Plugin "^GenericJMX$"
            PluginInstance "^jvm.*$"
            TypeInstance "^memorypool-usage_used$"
        </Match>
        <Target "set">
            MetaData "stackdriver_metric_type" "custom.googleapis.com/jvm/memorypool/usage_used"
            MetaData "label:pool" "%{plugin_instance}"
        </Target>
        <Target "replace">
            MetaData "label:pool" "jvm" ""
        </Target>
    </Rule>
    <Rule "rewrite_genericjmx_to_jvm">
        <Match regex>
            Plugin "^GenericJMX$"
            PluginInstance "^jvm.*$"
        </Match>
        <Target "replace">
            PluginInstance "jvm" ""
        </Target>
        <Target "set">
            Plugin "jvm"
        </Target>
        Target "return"
    </Rule>
</Chain>
```

The plugin instance is the pool name (e.g. G1 Eden Space) which is why I copied it into the 'pool' label.

This did auto-create the metric in Stackdriver but I also used the following body to the [projects.metricDescriptors.create](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.metricDescriptors/create) method to add description and units.

```
{
  "name": "projects/yourprojecthere/metricDescriptors/custom.googleapis.com/jvm/memorypool/usage_used",
  "labels": [
    {
      "key": "pool",
      "description": "Name of the JVM memory pool."
    }
  ],
  "metricKind": "GAUGE",
  "valueType": "DOUBLE",
  "unit": "By",
  "description": "Current size in bytes of the memory pool.",
  "type": "custom.googleapis.com/jvm/memorypool/usage_used",
  "monitoredResourceTypes": [
    "gce_instance"
  ]
}
```

The resulting graph in metric explorer looks like this
[image: metric explorer graph of memory pool usage]