# Stackdriver adding custom JMX metrics, similar to jvm-sun-hotspot

Tags: jmx, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, mbeans

I have been trying to monitor a custom JMX metrics using stackdriver,
. I saw the below GIT page for fetching MBEAN metrics,

https://github.com/Stackdriver/stackdriver-agent-service-configs/blob/master/etc/collectd.d/jvm-sun-hotspot.conf

I require some additional custom metrics thats needs to be monitored from Stackdriver. Basically, i need
openejb.management:ObjectType=datasources,DataSource=jdbc_db

I tried modifying the conf file from Github by removing the OOb Mbeans and added the custom MBEAN, and i changed the target set to

> <Target "set">
> MetaData "stackdriver_metric_type" "custom.googleapis.com/jvm/jmx/datasource/jdbc_db"

I see a new metric is getting propagated to Stack driver, but other OOb metrics are affected, Can anyone provide a conf file which i can deplot in /stackdriver/collectd/etc/collectd.d/ location which will sends the custom MBean to Stachdriver

Comment: have you installed the jvm agent metric?
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-jvm
also the jvm pluggin for this
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/jvm
so that you can have the logs monitored and metrics propagated to Stackdriver.
I also found a similar issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62414258/adding-custom-jmx-metrics-to-google-cloud-monitoring-collectd-configuration
I would recommend reading through the documentation and this stack question that could provide you with answers

Comment: I have installed the agent, and jvm plugin. The stacokoverflow page you pointed to doesnt explains whether a new conf file has been creatd or the jvm-sun-hotspot file has been modified.

Comment: I recommend you follow this guide [1] You will need to configure your own metric.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/custom-metrics-agent